# Download large files through android download manager

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, android-download-manager

Is it possible to download large files (> 2^31-1 bytes) through the android `DownloadManager`?
The question is caused by column `DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR` refers to `int` filed in database. What if bytes count will be more then `2^31-1`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In simple words: no it's not possible. Because file system will not be able to handle files of larger size

Comment: Why filesystem will not be able to do it?

Comment: as designed. I suggest you reading something about file systems to get familiar with this subject. http://www.all-things-android.com/content/understanding-android-file-hierarchy and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system to start with